# Can we use Azure event hub connecting to mobile app for real time syncs instead of querying Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a client app on windows tablet that syncs data up and down to and from Azure SQL. There is a timer in the app that checks for any updates on Azure SQL DB .It queries Azure SQL and checks for the new updates.I was just thinking of moving the update flags to Azure blob and use event hubs to ping the blob to check for any updates and then connect to Azure SQL and download/upload the data.Any help from someone who can share implementation details will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to check the updates in azure blob storage? if it's the case, I think you should consider [azure function blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) and no need to use event hub to ping blob storage.

Comment: Updates are very frequent and more than 500 users update the data. Do you think it is a good idea to initiate a function app trigger everytime there is an update?